# AI system attacking without spending mana c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently in the making of a Turned based ARPG game, however, I ran into an issue that I thought you guys might be able to help me with, I tried running the script, but it still attacks with spending "mana."

```
//without spending mana
           bool enoughAttackActionPoints = attack.actionPointsCost <= (playerTeam ? bm.GetRemainingActionPoints(true) : bm.GetRemainingActionPoints(false));
           bool canAttack = enoughAttackActionPoints;

           //For healing 
           bool enoughHealingActionPoints = attack.actionPointsCost <= (playerTeam ? bm.GetRemainingActionPoints(true) : bm.GetRemainingActionPoints(false));
           bool enoughMana = heal.attributeCost.Find(x => x.attributeId == "mp").cost <= ci.availableAttributes.Find(x => x.attributeId == "mp").currentValue;

           bool canHeal = enoughHealingActionPoints && enoughMana;
```

Comment: Just a thought; what about giving your AI just a huge mana pool that never runs out? that way most of your logic would remain the same between AI/non-ai agents?

Comment: Or your Ai such a huge regen it has the same effect

Comment: FYI: `(playerTeam ? bm.GetRemainingActionPoints(true) : bm.GetRemainingActionPoints(false))` is just a long-winded way of expressing `bm.GetRemainingActionPoints(playerTeam)`

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace This makes sense, do you have any recommendations on how i should write it differently?